# Rotating canvas and drawing bitmap performance

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rotation, frame-rate

I am trying to make a game where the planet would be in the center of user's screen and very slowly rotate like planet would.. So first I decided to test it if everything would work fine, and it doesn't.. I get a simple "planet" image like this:

`Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.totone);`

I also have a variable that stores the angle. Then in the draw function I just rotate the canvas, draw my planet (now rotated), and rotate canvas back. like this:

```
//the planet's image is 512x512px
canvas.rotate(ang,256,256); //256, 256 is the center of rotation
canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0,0, null);
canvas.rotate(-ang,256,256); //rotate back
```

I have no idea why, but it looks like when the image is rotated by 90 and 270 degrees the game fps slows a little? I made a little gif to show the problem. The fps is perfectly 60 all the time but then it drops at 50ish for couple miliseconds for no reason? What is causing this? I tried to change my thread's target fps to 30 and it looks like no fps drops happened then.. So it's probably performance issue. Note that  I tried rotating the bitmap using maany different methods, the fps drop effect is still the same..

[Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU0Wl.gif)

Comment: tried `canvas.concat(matrix)` followed by `canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null)`? or directly:`canvas.drawBitmap(image, matrix, null)`?

Comment: @pskink yes, sadly the same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is an interaction between the device's fixed screen refresh rate and a slight variation in the time it takes to draw the bitmap at certain angles.

I'm guessing that you increment `ang` by a constant amount in `onDraw()`. This fact can be used to explain the sharp change in rotation rate.

**EXPLANATION**

Your device refreshes its screen at 60Hz. That means `onDraw()` gets called at 60Hz, max, under ideal conditions: About once every 16.7ms.

Let's assume that `onDraw()` takes about 15ms to execute. There's 1.7ms left over; everything's fine! You get a nice, smooth, 60Hz rotation.

Then assume that, at certain values of `ang`, `onDraw()` takes just a little bit longer; say, 18ms. (I will speculate on why the execution time of `drawBitmap()` varies based on the angle in a moment. For now, let's look at what happens with this 18ms drawing time.)

Ideally, `onDraw()` gets called at 60Hz. But now you're taking too long; more than 1 cycle. The [compositor](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture) now has to drop a frame from your app, because you couldn't supply it fast enough! So, instead of  `onDraw()` executing every 16.7ms, now it can only be called every 33.4ms.

In other words, the screen hardware refreshes at a constant rate, and when your `onDraw()` crosses that 16.7ms threshold, your update rate gets cut exactly in half.

This is hinted at in your GIF. The displayed frame rate goes from 60 to 51, but it seems pretty clear to me the actual rotation rate drops by almost exactly 50%. I suspect the discrepancy is simply due to the way you calculated the displayed frame rate.

**SPECULATION ON VARIATION IN drawBitmap() EXECUTION TIME**

Could be the caching performance of the processor. At certain rotation angles, the graphics logic could be accessing bitmap memory in a way that is not ideal for the L1 cache/prefretching logic. In other words, you could be getting a lot of cache misses at these angles.

**RECOMMENDED FIXES FOR PLAYABILITY**

1. Use a faster graphics pipeline, such as OpenGL, and/or:
2. Base `ang` on a time hack (`uptimeMillis()`) instead of an increment. You'll still drop frames, but the apparent rotation rate will be corrected.
3. If you want to go really crazy, you could supply a second bitmap, pre-rotated 90 degrees to the first, and use this bitmap for draws that take place at angles closer to 90/270 degrees. If I'm right about the cache misses, this would ameliorate the problem.

Comment: @Paper Eh? No? No dice?